# Chosen not work after ajax call

Tags: php, ajax, jquery-chosen

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/harvesthq/chosen/gh-pages/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/harvesthq/chosen/gh-pages/chosen.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

HTML
    
        Towns

```
    <select class="form-control select2 chosen-select" id="propertyCity" name="propertyCity[]" style="width:90%;" multiple="multiple" data-tags="true">

<optgroup label="Alajuela">
    <option value="Alaj_Alajuela">Alajuela</option>
    <option value="Alaj_Atenas">Atenas</option>
    <option value="Alaj_Grecia">Grecia</option>
    <option value="Alaj_La Fortuna">La Fortuna</option>
    <option value="Alaj_La Garita">La Garita</option>
    <option value="Alaj_La Guacima">La Guacima</option>
    <option value="Alaj_Orotina">Orotina</option>
    <option value="Alaj_San Carlos">San Carlos</option>
    <option value="Alaj_San Ramon">San Ramon</option>
    <option value="Alaj_Upala">Upala</option>
        </optgroup>                 
    </select>
    </div>
```

SCRIPT

```
jQuery(".chosen-select").chosen({
  no_results_text: "Oops, nothing found!"
    })
```

this above code works first time but when i get response from ajax and replace my dropdown values then chosen not worked.

This is my ajax function success code

```
success: function( response ) {
           $(".townsclss").html(response);
           $("#propertyCity").addClass("chosen-select");
           $("#propertyCity").trigger("chosen:updated");
           $(select).trigger("chosen:updated");
 }
```

Response comes in sucess:

```
<div id="propertyCityReplace">
 <label for="propertyCity" style="width:90px;"> City </label><br />
        <select class="form-control select2" id="propertyCity" name="propertyCity[]" style="width:90
%;" multiple="multiple" data-tags="true">

    <optgroup label='Limón'>
<option value='Lim_Cahuita'>Cahuita</option>
<option value='Lim_Caribbean Coast'>Caribbean Coast</option>
<option value='Lim_Guacimo'>Guacimo</option>
<option value='Lim_Puerto Limon'>Puerto Limon</option>
<option value='Lim_Puerto Viejo'>Puerto Viejo</option></optgroup>                   
</select>               
    </div>
```

Can you help me why chosen not worked after ajax call?

Answer (score 0):

Because `jQuery(".chosen-select").chosen({`... runs only at page load. The ajax changes the DOM elements and the events are gone.

You have call

```
jQuery(".chosen-select").chosen({
    no_results_text: "Oops, nothing found!"
})
```

after the ajax call, right after

```
$("#propertyCity").addClass("chosen-select");
```